# BigQuery internal error on a GROUP by query (trigrams)

Tags: group-by, aggregate-functions, google-bigquery

I tried the following query with LIMIT 100 and got a "Resources exceeded during query execution" (otichyproject1:job_1mpw4aDtTHmbduBdKSBu5ty1DXY) so I tried to output it into a new table and allow large results. It ran much longer, but failed with 'internal error' (otichyproject1:job_6pFUlj2AzdROUyAU8nZ9dGdo3ms).

```
SELECT 
 ngram, decade, SUM(freq) totalfreq, SUM(books) totalbooks 
FROM 
 trigram.trigrams3 
GROUP BY 
 ngram, decade
```

The table trigrams3 is derived from the public trigram dataset and should be smaller (although the COUNT on the trigrams give weird results).

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Can you share publicly the dataset? Then I would be able to try

Comment: I added all authenticated users: can view to the dataset - otichyproject1:trigram. The table in question is trigrams3 which I have derived from the public trigram dataset by google as follows:

(inserting into trigrams1)
SELECT ngram, cell.value year, cell.match_count freq, cell.volume_count books FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams]

(inserting into trigrams2)
SELECT * FROM trigram.trigrams1 WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(ngram, r'^[A-Za-z\'\-\s]+$')

(inserting into trigrams3)
SELECT ngram, LEFT(year) decade, freq, books FROM trigram.trigrams2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's see how big the result set is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT ngram, decade, SUM(freq) totalfreq, SUM(books) totalbooks 
FROM  [otichyproject1:trigram.trigrams3]
GROUP EACH BY ngram, decade
)
```

837,369,607 - almost a billion registers to output, that's why we need "allowLargeResults".

Note that I used "GROUP EACH". "EACH" shouldn't be needed as it's in its way out, but it improves running time for me here.

Same with LIMIT 100, it works with "EACH":

```
SELECT 
 ngram, decade, SUM(freq) totalfreq, SUM(books) totalbooks 
FROM 
 trigram.trigrams3 
GROUP EACH BY 
 ngram, decade
LIMIT 100
```

And the query to output all results to a new table, runs in only 20 seconds if I try it with "EACH" and "AllowLargeResults":

```
SELECT ngram, decade, SUM(freq) totalfreq, SUM(books) totalbooks 
FROM  [otichyproject1:trigram.trigrams3]
GROUP EACH BY ngram, decade
```

So the short answer to this question is: Keep using "GROUP EACH" (for now).

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! And kudos for the reaction time :)

Comment: once I see a shared dataset, I can't stop myself from helping :)